# Android Textview- Non English Charecter from Mysql

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I'm using volley to fetch data (as json array) from MySQL DB to a android-RecyclerView which contains mixed languages (English and Malayalam). Malayalam characters are not  displayed correctly.

When I try to change typeface

```
Typeface mtf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "AnjaliOldLipi.ttf");
holder.cat.setTypeface(mtf);
```

works fine, only if I set text like this

```
holder.cat.setText("ഹൌ ഈസ് ദാറ്റ്");
```

But does't work like this

```
holder.cat.setText(model.getCat());
```

please help me to sort this out.
Thank you

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the value returned by `getCat()` then.

Comment: getCat() returns a String, in my case `????`